# Java. Type vs Object of a class

Tags: java, object, types, subclass, hierarchy

For example, when I have a class Rectangle, and a class Square. If class Square extends Rectangle, therefore class square is a subclass of class Rectangle. Now say I had the code. `Rectangle shape = new Square(5,6);`
I would be creating an object, but would it be type Rectangle, but using the constructor of square, or an object of Square?, my confusion starts with class Square has the same methods of class Rectangle, but it will use the methods in class Square not class Rectangle. So did I create an object of Square, but have type Rectangle?

Comment: Everyone is getting angry knowing square does not extend rectangle, but this was my teachers example purely showing inheritance, infact at the end he was showing how if we use this code, it creates a bug.

Comment: As an aside, `Square extends Rectangle` may not be a great idea. While it's true that in geometry, a square is a rectangle, in terms of the API they're not. A rectangle probably has `setHeight` and `setWidth` methods, with the assumption that setting one won't affect the other. But a Square just as `setLength`, which affects both the height and the width. Even if you have them share method names, the behavior is different enough that it's probably not good to have Square extend Rectangle.

Comment: @yshavit:  So long as the length and width are equivalent, a square is no different in principle to a rectangle.

Comment: @Makoto If you had a `Rectangle rect` with width=5 and height=5, and you called `rect.setHeight(2)`, what would you expect `rect.getWidth()` to be? I'd expect it to stay at 5, not be changed to 2. Now, maybe a careful read of the JavaDocs would reveal something like "changing the width may or may not also change the height," but (a) that's [easy to miss](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and (b) that makes it harder to reason about your program, since you have to keep more "maybe"s in your head.

Comment: @yshavit:  That's why you'd use the more concrete `Square` if you actually wanted a square.  What I'm saying is, from a geometrical (and likely implementation) sense, so long as the length and width of the rectangle were equivalent, then it'd be no different than having a square.  (My immediate preference would be to make the shape then *immutable* so that you don't get those wonky behaviors, but...)

Comment: What yshavit said about it not being a good idea makes sense _if the class is mutable_ -- that is, if your `Rectangle` is really going to provide the ability to change its size at runtime.  But in a lot of applications, it would be immutable--you set the height and width when you construct it, and don't provide methods to change them later.  Moral: you need to think about whether you're going to extend a class like this when you're thinking about whether the class should be immutable or not.

Comment: Then again, if it's immutable, then what does the type Square even give you? That is, what's the advantage of a Square vs a Rectangle that just happens to have equal sides? I suppose that's more detailed an API discussion than these comments are meant for, but I submit that in _most_ cases, Square extends Rectangle is either confusing or unneeded.

Comment: I don't know--maybe there's some interesting method that applies only to `Square` and not to `Rectangle`?  It's hard to answer a question like "why would you want this", when we're dealing with types that they use in textbooks that are so trivial that no one would ever use any of them anyway.  I personally have never seen production code that declares a type `Animal` with `Dog` and `Cat` as subclasses.  But the idea is to teach the concepts that will be used to build type hierarchies that _are_ useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confuses a lot of people.  Let me try to break it down.

When you say `new Square`, the object is created using the `Square` constructor.  The object will have type `Square` throughout its existence.

When you declare a variable with type `Rectangle`, i.e. `Rectangle x;` or `Rectangle x = (anything);` you're telling the compiler that `x` (when it's not null) will always be a reference to `Rectangle` *or any of its subclasses* (including `Square`).  When you say `Rectangle x = new Square(...)`, `x` will be a reference to a `Square`, which is a `Rectangle`.  **However**, `x` could later be reassigned to become some other `Rectangle` that isn't a `Square`.

That means that, when you say `x.method(...)`, the compiler only allows you to use the methods that are defined in `Rectangle`, because the compiler only knows that `x` is a `Rectangle` or some subclass.  If you declare a new method in `Square`, you can't use it with the above call.

However, if `x` still is a reference to a `Square`, then when you call a method defined in `Rectangle`, the program will actually run the method you wrote for `Square` (if you've overridden the one in `Rectangle`).

Maybe this example will help.  Suppose that `Rectangle` declares `public` methods `aaa` and `bbb`.  In `Square`, you write an overriding method `aaa`, you don't override `bbb`, and you declare a new public method `ccc`.

```
Rectangle x = new Square(10);
Rectangle y = new Rectangle(5,6);

// assume that x and y aren't changed 

x.aaa();   // runs the overriding method aaa in Square
y.aaa();   // runs the method aaa in Rectangle

x.bbb();   // runs the method in Rectangle, since it's not overridden.  But
           // if bbb calls aaa, then it will call the aaa in Square.
y.bbb();   // runs the method in Rectangle

x.ccc();   // illegal.  Even though the object is actually a Square, the
           // compiler isn't allowed to know that.
y.ccc();   // illegal

((Square)x).ccc();  // This is how you can get to the new method that you
           // declared in Square.  Even though the compiler doesn't know 
           // that x is a Square, when you use the cast, you tell the 
           // compiler that it's OK fo treat it as a Square, and to access
           // the method defined only in Square.
((Square)y).ccc();  // Will throw ClassCastException at runtime, because 
           // y isn't a Square.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this answered all my questions :D

Comment: @stackflow420 If you feel this answer best addressed your questions, you should mark it as the answer. Currently, the accepted answer on this question is Epsilon_'s, which means that that's the one you've said is most helpful. It also means that it's the highest answer on this page, and thus the most visible to anyone else who comes across this from a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You created an object of type Square.

A call to `new Foo(...)` will *always* create a Foo, no exceptions. And it'll always call the constructor for `Foo`, again without exceptions. That said, if Foo extends from another class, then the first thing Foo's constructor will do is to invoke the superclass's constructor. Again, there are no exceptions to this, ever — though you won't necessarily see it in the code, because if you don't have a call to `super(...)` and there exists a no-argument constructor in the super class, then the compiler will automatically invoke that constructor for you. But one way or the other, it'll always get invoked.

Since you've set it up that a Square is-a rectangle, that object is also an instance of Rectangle. With your classes, a Square is always a Rectangle, but not all Rectangles are Squares.

The `Rectangle shape` bit just means that as far as the *compiler* knows, it's "at least" a Rectangle. It may be exactly a Rectangle, or it may be a subclass of Rectangle (like Square) -- but it won't be, for instance, a Number.

When you call `shape.getArea()` (for instance), the JVM will look up the *actual* type of `shape` — not just its compile-time type, but the type it was actually created as when you invoked `new` — and invoke the method that that class defines.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance always gives your objects an [**is-a** relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a).  So, by virtue of `Square` extending `Rectangle`, it's safe to say that a `Square` **is-a** `Rectangle`.

You have created an instance of `Square`, but you will only be able to use the methods provided by its parent `Rectangle` on it.

Comment: So you are saying you can't call methods that belong to Square?

Comment: If you are referring to the instance of that `Square` as a `Rectangle`, that's right.  Because the parent class doesn't know about the child class' methods, nothing that the child defines can be used by the parent.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is answer to question "Is Square really a rectangle?". From gemoetry perspective answer is yes but from software perspective answer may not be so obvious.
"Is-a" relationship has to follow [Liskov Substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

So essentially if base class has some methods which are not applicable for derived class then its not a "is-a" relationship.

e.g.

class Rectangle{

/**Constructor Code**/

public void changeWidth(){....}
  public void changeLength(){....}

}

changeWidth and changeLength are two functions which make perfect sense for a rectangle but not for Square since all sides are equal in square. Though you can hack and give your own implementation of both function in square class still from my point of view relationship does not look natural.

As for other answers I do agree with them.

Answer (score -2):

That's called Polymorphism, do your homework. the shape variable is only a reference but the real object is a Square object.